# Difference between admin-c and tech-c

Tags: whois

I am confused about the role of the admin-c, especially in relation to the tech-c.

[RIPE](http://www.ripe.net/) defines the admin-c as a technical contact that is
onsite.

> "admin-c" (administrative contact) and "tech-c" (technical contact)
>   are network contacts, required to be listed by their nic-handles in
>   certain RIPE Database objects. This is done for operational
>   correspondence such as Network troubleshooting. The admin-c must be
>   physically located at the site of the network. The tech-c does not
>   need to be physically located at the site of the network.
>   http://www.ripe.net/data-tools/db/faq/faq-db/what-is-a-tech-c-and-what-is-an-admin-c

DENIC defines the admin-c as a non technical contact.

> To solve this problem and to make domain administration as easy and
>   efficient as possible DENIC (like nearly all other domain registries)
>   has created the role of the Admin-C. With the Admin-C, the domain
>   holder officially registers an authorized representative with DENIC,
>   who will then be entitled to make statements in the name of the domain
>   holder without having to prove his/her authorization in every
>   individual case.
>   [enter link description here](https://www.secure.denic.de/en/faq-single/562/1/252.html?cHash=6f43e62a4b6cc80b918ce7bec3b35eb6)

1&1 FAQ is more concise but similar to the DENIC definition.

> Admin-C (Administrative Contact) 
>        Contact person for the domain for administrative, non-technical matters. Example, for legal matters, change of ownership, etc.
>
> ```
>  Tech-C (Technical Contact) 
>  Contact person for domain's technical matters.
> ```
>
> [enter link description here](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/domains/domain_admin/domain_contact/1.html)

**What is the difference between admin-c and tech-c?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers are in the quotes you gave. First, if in doubt, RIPE beats DENIC, and DENIC beats 1&1 when it comes to definitions. But all three of them are pretty much telling the same story, although with different amounts of detail:

> The admin-c must be physically located at the site of the network. The
>   tech-c does not need to be physically located at the site of the
>   network

OK, this is RIPE's definition. Not sure *why* exactly, but this doesn't really say anything about the *role*.

DENIC says, that the Admin-C is responsible for all *administrative* matters - means *business*, not technical stuff.

1&1 pretty much says the same.

I think this is a confusion of the term "administration". It's *not* referring to system-administration, but *business-adminstration*.

Therefore, the Tech-C does techy stuff. Admin-C does business.

Comment: "admin-c and tech-c are network contacts, required to be listed by their nic-handles in certain RIPE Database objects. This is done for operational correspondence such as Network troubleshooting." This makes it pretty clear that RIPE means network administration in both cases, IMHO.

Comment: @LudwigWeinzierl I interprete this in a way, that someone may also contact Admin-C - who then in turn might to hand it over to Tech-C. But yes, from the words of RIPE, you're correct.